# Can CSS find an element that has ANY id?

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of the same elements on a page that is not under my direct control (so i can't change the HTML). This might look like this:

```
<div class="item">This text should be black</div>
<div class="item" id="brand_one">This text should be red</div>
<div class="item" id="brand_two">This text should be red</div>
...
<div class="item">This text should be black</div>
```

I want to write a css rule that targets **all** elements with class **item** that have an id.

I can do

```
#brand_one, #brand_two, ... { color:red; }
```

But the id's go into the hundreds, so that's not an option.

What i'm looking for is a rule something like this:

```
.item[id] { color:red; } / .item# { color:red; }
```

I know this is possible in Javascript, but does this exist in CSS?

Comment: I think you need to use CSS variables, if i'm not mistaken, that's SCSS.

Comment: I dont see why you need to do that as an ID needs to be unique. it would make more sence if you were trying to do this with classes

Comment: As you can see in his example, @Andrew, the first div with class `item` has to be black, while the next ones (the ones with a div id of `brand_#`) have to be red. The only way he can make a difference between the first div and divs that contain `brand_#` is by targeting the divs that contain an id with `brand_`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
.item[id] {
    /* any elements with a class .item and an ID attribute */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this exists. In you case you should use:

```
div[id*="brand"]  { color: red; }
```

This selects all `div`s with an id that contains `brand` and colors it red.

Edit: You can also, to make sure it only targets `id`s with `brand_` in the start of the `id`-name, use the following:

```
div[id^="brand_"] { color: red; }
```

This will avoid that other `div`s in the future that have an `id` that contains `brand` will also be targeted.

Edit 2: To make it even MORE specific, you can target only `id`s that are following the `class="item"`:

```
div[id^="brand_"].item { color: red; }
```

This targets all `div`s with `brand_` in the beginning of the `id` and have `item` as a `class`.

Comment: Went with this option - strangely enough my own solution of .item[id] didn't work, but this seems to work, so thanks!

Comment: It should've worked, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v1uw1eeL/. However, in my opinion it's too broad and you have the risk of accidentally targeting some future divs :)

Comment: Please keep in mind, that selectors with a regular expression in it (which is any attribute selector with a modifier before the equal sign; e.g. `^=`, `$=`, `*=`) are the slowest selectors one can use. If you use really lot of them, it can lead to CSS rendering performance issues.

Comment: @feeela I suppose that was obvious but you really made me think on it.  I wonder if there's any research on the performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
.item[id^="brand"]{
    color:red;
}
```

^= indicates "starts with". So we can search id which starts with "brand".

Answer (score 1):

You can try using css attribute selector:

```css
div.item {
  color: black;
}
div.item[id^='brand_'] {
  color: red;
}
div.code {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.code[id^='brand_'] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">This text should be black</div>
<div class="item" id="brand_one">This text should be red</div>
<div class="item" id="brand_two">This text should be red</div>
<div class="item">This text should be black</div>
<div class="code">This text should be in caps</div>
<div class="code" id="brand_three">This text should be in caps and blue color</div>
```

Here, `[id^='brand_']` refers to `id` starting with `brand_`. There are also `$`(ends with) and `*`(contains) expressions.

Comment: In your case I would target `'brand_'`, since it's more specific for this case and prevents accidentally coloring some future `div`s with the `id` of `brand` red :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS [attribute^=value] Selector**

The [attribute^=value] selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

So in your case ;

```
<style>
 [id^="brand"] {
   color:red;
 }
<style>
```

Refer to:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

[Try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_attribute_start)

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .item:not([id='']) {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

But it assumes you can set id='':

`<div class="item" id="">This text should be black</div>`

Not sure how this would work when id is unspecified as in your case.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned he would have to set id=''. http://jsfiddle.net/oou66fft/ Feela has the right answer anyway.